# Как сделать запрос по href не используя selenium?

Tags: python, html

У меня есть сайт, на котором мне надо спарсить блок с информацией, которая же появляется если нажать на кнопку на сайте (ну точнее это не кнопка, а ссылка замаскированная под неё [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]) Далее появляется всплывающее окно, которое проверяет аккаунт и создаёт тот самый блок, который мне и нужно спарсить  [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы это имеете в виду: <a href="URL">...</a>

Comment: не понятно что вам надо спарсить

Comment: Согласен с Alexandr

Comment: @Alexandr, спарсить я и сам могу, мне надо как-то по ссылке перейти, чтобы появился блок, который нужно спарсить

Comment: Блок, который нужно спарсить на самом нижнем скриншоте, а кнопка, которую нужно нажать на первых 2х скринах

Comment: Ну не хотите Селениум, так не используйте Селениум :) Установите веб-прокси типа Фиддлера, посмотрите, какие HTTP-запросы идут к сайту магазина, и отправляйте эти запросы напрямую через библиотеку Requests. Иногда это проще, чем мучаться с Селениумом, иногда - сложнее. Тут как повезёт)